# Cycles of real functions and the derivative operator

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If you start with $\sin(x)$ and take four derivatives, you get three distinct functions and then end up back at $\sin(x)$. For $e^{-x}$, you take two. For $e^{x}$, you only need to take one.

Generally, I will call an N-cycle of the derivative operator a sequence of real valued functions of a real variable including $f(x)$ where,
$$
\frac{d^Nf}{dx^N}=f(x)
$$
but,
$$
\frac{d^mf}{dx^m}\neq f(x)
$$
for every $m$ that is not a multiple of $n$.

Over the complex numbers, these functions are simply $\exp( x\sqrt[N]1)$. For $N=1,2,4$ there are cycles of real functions, which in the case of $N=4$ may be constructed as a linear combination of the complex functions. Can there be cycles of real functions of length other than 1,2 or 4? If so, how may they be obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the real or imaginary part of a complex cycle.  Thus if $\alpha + \beta i$ is a complex $n$'th root of unity, take
$$f(x) = \text{Re}(\exp((\alpha+i \beta) x)) = \exp(\alpha x) \cos(\beta x)$$
and you'll have $$f^{(k)}(x) = \text{Re}((\alpha +\beta I)^k \exp((\alpha + I\beta) x))$$
and in particular $f^{(n)} = f$.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles of every length exist. Consider the solutions to the differential equation $f^{(n)}(x) -f(x)=0$. The solutions of this form a $n$-dimensional vector space, all of which are either $n$-cycles or cycles of some shorter length $d$ dividing $n$. Also, every $n$-cycle is a solution to this differential equation, by definition.

So then, for each $d|n$, the cycles of length dividing $d$ form a subspace of dimension at most $d$ in this larger vector space. A union of finitely many proper vector subspaces over $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be the whole space, and there is something in the space which has minimum cycle length $n$. Done.

We can also find solutions explicitly. If $\omega = \alpha +\beta i$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, $e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)$ and $e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)$ are $n$-cycles. This comes from using the similarity between constant-coefficent differential equations and polynomial equations - we factor the "polynomial" differential operator $D^n-1$, and the factor corresponding to the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial gives us $n$-cycles.